# Angular form checkbox not initially included in the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I am building a dynamic form that could include any number of field combinations and field types. A typical example of this might be a user registration with firstName, lastName, email and password. However also to be included on some forms would be a boolean checkbox for a field like active.

I have an empty object in my controller that will be populated by the form and then submitted. I attach `ng-model`to all of the form elements as usual, these all work well until I get to the boolean field which does not get included in the model unless the user has interacted with it.

The boolean field is usually required at the server side so I want it to be checked by default, but this won't be added to the model unless you first uncheck it and check it again.

`$scope.formData = {}`

```
<div class="{{field.name}}">
    <label for={{field.name}} class="field-label">{{field.prettyName}}</label>
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        class="form-field boolean-checkbox" 
        id={{field.name}} 
        ng-model="formData[field.name]"
        ng-checked="true"
    /> 
</div>
```

So the scenarios are:

Initial page load checkbox is checked but object reads as:

```
{}
```

The user then has to uncheck the checkbox, and then recheck it and the object will read as:

```
{
    "active":true
}
```

I have also tried using `ng-init="true"` but no joy there.

Comment: `formData[field.name]` does not exist so it is going to be false. You could run it through a function and set it to true if it does not exist yet.

Comment: Maybe if you try ng-init="formData[field.name] = true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) didn't work for you, but here's an example using it, as [luk492](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102135/luk492) stated in its comment (**you need to check your console logs to see it working**):

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.formData = {};

      $scope.$watch(function() {
        console.log('formData', JSON.stringify($scope.formData, null, 4))
      });
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-init="formData.truthyValue = true" ng-model="formData.truthyValue">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-init="formData.falsyValue = false" ng-model="formData.falsyValue">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

You'll see that both `truthyValue` and `falsyValue` are added to `formData` regardless of their boolean value.

An important thing to note from [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) docs is that **you shouldn't use it together with ngModel**, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Ah thank you very much @cosmin-ababei I hadn't gone far enough with ng-init it seems as I merely had `ng-init="true"` rather than `ng-init="formData[field.name] = true"`. As far as ng-checked goes, I did see in the docs that it wasn't meant to be used but without the ng-init working properly I couldn't get it to check as default. Thank you again for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

If your form has the named Option `ng-checked="true"` at the start, then you could use a "constant" on the back-end. So if the form returned following data:

```
{ NULL }
```

then you could use your constant instead, because the form is on true.
And if the user changed the Option, you could use the form-value instead

```
{
    "active":true
}
```

*If you got any further question, don't hestitate to comment my answer. :)*

Comment: Thank you for answering @kyon, I'm a little unclear as to what you mean by using a "constant" on the back-end instead? Do you have an example?

Comment: @DanHodson, just use a if-clause. => if Response == NULL { check = true } else { check = form.value }